# Adding items to an object through the .push() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I'm doing a loop through few input elements of 'checkbox' type. After that, I'm adding values and checked attributes to an array. This is my code:

```
var stuff = {};
$('form input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    stuff[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).attr('checked');
});
```

This works fine, but I'm just wondering if I can do the exact same thing with .push() method in Jquery?

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
stuff.push( {$(this).attr('value'):$(this).attr('checked')} );
```

**Edit:**

I was trying to use .push() method on Object, but .push() is actually just a method of Array Object.

Comment: It is not possible that your second example works if you really are initializing "stuff" as you describe.

Comment: maybe i've tried that example when stuff was initialized as "var stuff = [];". I think you're right, yeah...

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**[`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** is a method of the **[Built-in Array Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**

It is not related to jQuery in any way.

You are defining a literal **Object** with

```
// Object
var stuff = {};
```

You can define a literal **Array** like this

```
// Array
var stuff = [];
```

then

```
stuff.push(element);
```

---

Arrays actually get their bracket syntax `stuff[index]` inherited from their parent, the Object.  This is why you are able to use it the way you are in your first example.

This is often used for effortless reflection for dynamically accessing properties

```
stuff = {}; // Object

stuff['prop'] = 'value'; // assign property of an 
                         // Object via bracket syntax

stuff.prop === stuff['prop']; // true
```

Answer (score 22):

so it's easy)))

Watch this...

```
    var stuff = {};
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, e) {
        stuff[i] = e.checked;
    });
```

And you will have:

```
Object {0: true, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false}
```

Or:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, e) {
    stuff['row'+i] = e.checked;
});
```

You will have:

```
Object {row0: true, row1: false, row2: false, row3: false}
```

Or:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(i, e) {
    stuff[e.className+i] = e.checked;
});
```

You will have:

```
Object {checkbox0: true, checkbox1: false, checkbox2: false, checkbox3: false}
```

Answer (score 15):

`stuff` is an object and `push` is a method of an array. **So you cannot use `stuff.push(..)`.**

Lets say you define `stuff` as an array `stuff = [];` **then you can call `push` method on it.**

This works because the object[key/value] is well formed.

`stuff.push( {'name':$(this).attr('checked')} );`

Whereas this will not work because the object is not well formed.

`stuff.push( {$(this).attr('value'):$(this).attr('checked')} );`

This works because we are treating `stuff` as an associative array and added values to it

`stuff[$(this).attr('value')] = $(this).attr('checked');`

Comment: This does not explain why `stuff.push( {'name':$(this).attr('checked')} );` works. Honestly, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 13):

This is really easy:
Example

```
//my object
var sendData = {field1:value1, field2:value2};

//add element
sendData['field3'] = value3;
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way of doing it would be:

```
stuff = Object.assign(stuff, {$(this).attr('value'):$(this).attr('checked')});
```

Read more here: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score -1):

Today you can use destructuring to make these things for you!

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Destructuring works both for arrays and objects too. You can just put:

```js
let stuff = {
  text: "value"
}
// create some other value
const anotherVariable = 10
stuff = {
...stuff,
anotherVariable
}

console.log(stuff)
```

And the output will be: `{text: "value", anotherVariable: 10}`