# object.push is not a function [Node/Socket.io]

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, socket.io

```
var object = {

}

socket.on('call', function(data){
  console.log(data); // On console: { number: 68, name: 'John' }
  object.push(data);
});
```

In the console.log I get  the object just fine. But the push function doesn't seem to be working.

```
    object.push(data);
            ^
 
TypeError: object.push is not a function
```

Comment: push can be used for `array` not for `object`

Comment: `push` is a member function of `Array`, not `Object`. You can't "push" anything into an object. Try `var arr = []; ... arr.push(data);`;

Comment: Sorry, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7261466/8241267 this answer really tripped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` here is an `Object`, so not have the `push` function.

If you want to use an object use `object[key] = value;` or `object.key = value;`

---

`Array.push` in others hand exists.

```
var object = [];

object.push(value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is it a good idea to have an array with a bunch of objects inside it?

Comment: @TwitchClips, in JS you can push objects inside an array. It is not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `push()` function for `Objects`. Actually there is no function named `push()` for Objects. You need to use an `Array` if you want to use `push`.

Hope this code helps.

```js
  var myArray = ['A','B'];
  myArray.push('C');
  console.log(myArray);
  //["A", "B", "C"]

  var myObject = {foo:"bar"};
  myObject.name = "John";
  console.log(myObject);
  //{foo: "bar", name: "John"}
```